# Use of unresolved identifier 'NSInsertedObjectsKey'

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to observe `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave` notification.

```
_ = NotificationCenter.default.rx
        .notification(Notification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextDidSave)
        .takeUntil(rx.methodInvoked(#selector(viewWillDisappear(_:))))
        .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] notification in
            if let inserts = notification.userInfo?[NSInsertedObjectsKey] as? Set<NSManagedObject>, inserts.count > 0 {
                // Use of unresolved identifier 'NSInsertedObjectsKey'
            }
        })
```

I have used `RxSwift` for handling the notification.

The problem is, `NSInsertedObjectsKey` is considered as an *unresolved identifier* and I don't think it has been changed to something else as all the document, including `Apple`'s, that I can find suggest that I should use `NSInsertedObjectsKey`.

I also tried typing `InsertedObjectsKey` but didn't work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know to get that error is if you don't have `import CoreData` at the top of your file. The variable is declared in the Core Data framework, so it can't be resolved unless that framework is imported.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I was using a CoreData wrapper library so I did not have `import CoreData` in my code.